# Mono and MongoDB on Raspbian

Tags: linux, mongodb, mono, raspbian

I've written and tested a c# application in visual studio.

..but now need to cross compile it with Mono on a Raspberry PI (set up as a headless server).

I'm having trouble with the MongoDB Driver -- it's not available as default in the build.

I'm including this .. which works fine on windows

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
```

But in Linux on the RasPi This is the error:

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name `MongoDB' could not be
>   found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Can I install the MongodB driver using apt-get?

or .. this repo should help me... If I can compile it..

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver

how do I go about doing that? clone the repo and run the build.sh ?

Once I do that is this the command that will include it in my build?

```
Something like:  "mcs pkg:mongodb.pkg myapp.cs"
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The [mono documentation](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=man%3amcs%281%29) talks about how to include packages, towards the bottom of the page. From what I can tell you need something like `mcs -pkg:mongodb myapp.cs`.

Comment: That's pretty close to what I need...  If I can just find out if there is a mongoDB driver installed in mono on my raspberrypi...  if I can install one using apt-get ... and/or if I need to compile a driver from source for the ARM cpu.  Ill keep looking, your link is leading me down a few directions I had not seen.